# GPS coordinates not coming in UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata

Tags: ios, objective-c, gps, uiimage

I am trying to get loctaion from the meta data of the image clicked from camera.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    NSDictionary *metadata = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata];
    NSLog(@"%@",metadata);


}
```

the log i am getting is

> ```
> {
> DPIHeight = 72;
> DPIWidth = 72;
> Orientation = 6;
> "{Exif}" =     {
>     ApertureValue = "2.526068811667588";
>     BrightnessValue = "1.530886431890497";
>     ColorSpace = 1;
>     DateTimeDigitized = "2013:01:11 14:58:42";
>     DateTimeOriginal = "2013:01:11 14:58:42";
>     ExposureMode = 0;
>     ExposureProgram = 2;
>     ExposureTime = "0.0303030303030303";
>     FNumber = "2.4";
>     Flash = 32;
>     FocalLenIn35mmFilm = 35;
>     FocalLength = "1.85";
>     ISOSpeedRatings =         (
>         320
>     );
>     MeteringMode = 5;
>     PixelXDimension = 640;
>     PixelYDimension = 480;
>     SceneType = 1;
>     SensingMethod = 2;
>     ShutterSpeedValue = "5.058893689053568";
>     WhiteBalance = 0;
> };
> "{TIFF}" =     {
>     DateTime = "2013:01:11 14:58:42";
>     Make = Apple;
>     Model = "iPad 2";
>     Software = "6.0";
>     XResolution = 72;
>     YResolution = 72;
> };
> }
> ```

but theres no gps co ordinate. 
Note- i dont have core location manager in my class. I am not sure if it is required. Do i have to programmatically add GPS coordinates to my image by using core location services?

Comment: note- i am not doing anything additional for attaching gps coordinates in metadata, i was thinking if location services is on for my camera then it will automatically add location in my app

Comment: Do the GPS coordinates show up in Preview ?

Comment: actually I am not saving this image in the album. I was wondering, when camera gets on from my application, iOS never asks for permission to allow my application to use my location. I guess i have to programmatically add GPS coordinates in the meta data of the image, and yes if i take log of photos from my camera album pictures, then it shows the gps coordinate in the log